# TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined, Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'sanitar')) {
    if (message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
      const user = message.mentions.users.first();
      if (user != undefined) {
        user.GuildMemberRoleManager.add(635602511964667907);
        message.channel.send(`<:mebel:632608605635608578> | Пользователь ${user} был отправлен в дурку ебать!`);
      } else {
        message.channel.send('<:mebel:632608605635608578> | Пингани кого-то, идиот.');
        message.channel.send('<:debil:691052950998482955>');
      }
    } else {
      message.channel.send('<:mebel:632608605635608578> | У вас недостаточно прав для этого действия!');
    }
  }
});
```

I'm trying to create an add-role command for my discord.js bot, but when it gets to `user.GuildMemberRoleManager.add(635602511964667907);`

i get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined.

I also tried to use `user.Addrole` function, but i get:

> user.Addrole is not a function.

Maybe addrole is outdated now, idk. I am very tired of this, so can somebody help me to fix it pls...

Comment: I never used DiscordJS, but you are checking that user isn't undefined before executing this line, so it's the property GuildMemberRoleManager that should be undefined

Comment: Are you trying to create a new role, or are you trying to give a person in the guild a role? Also, there is documentation for Discord.js at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `roles` not `GuildMemberRoleManager` since `roles` returns `GuildMemberRoleManager` of the `GuildMember`.

Also `User` does not have `roles` only `GuildMember` does so you have to replace `const user = message.mentions.users.first();` with `const user = message.mentions.members.first();`

You also need to pass the role ID as a string, not a number.

```js
user.roles.add('635602511964667907');
```

Also, you are correct, `addRole()` is not a function and has deprecated since discord.js v12.

Comment: there is still TypeError: cannot read property 'add' of undefined at `user.roles.add('635602511964667907');`